# C# tool for webpage "save as" and offline browsing

Tags: c#, offline

Is there any opensource tool in C# that can do a webpage "save as" or "save" and download all contents, so that later I can perform an offline browsing?

EDIT:
As a side note, I want the tool to allow me to save contents from hotmail as well.

Comment: hope this helps: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any specific tool however, the .NET framework has classes for making HTTP requests and an open source library called the "Html Agility Pack" is available on CodePlex which does a good job of parsing Html. By combining these tools, you could probably fairly easily write one yourself. I've used the Html Agility Pack myself in the past to obtain the Daily Dilbert cartoon just to see if it could be done (someone else had already done it of course), and the Html Agility Pack was good enough for that, if memory serves.

Comment: let me check it, I need something that saves my time, but I dont want to extract out lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

There is (e.g.) a tool called [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) that will do this for you.

If you like a programmatic solution, I once created [a library in C# to crawl and download websites](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaWebSpider.aspx).

Comment: Pretty close to what I need. But I will check it out as well.

Comment: Thanks. Solved most of the issue I had.

Comment: Would you mind telling me on how to save the actual crawled file to the disk?